# Ошибка "$apply already in progress" в событии FileReader.onloadstart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

Столкнулся с разным поведением скрипта в браузерах **Mozilla Firefox v56.0** и **Google Chrome v61.0**.

Разница в `$digest` цикле. В Мозиле возникает ошибка **$apply already in progress**.

Пример:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('downloadCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.stages = [];
  $scope.download = function() {
    let file = new Blob(["Sample text data"]);
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadstart = function() {
      console.log("onloadstart");
      $scope.stages.push('onloadstart');
      $scope.$apply();
    };
    fileReader.onload = function() {
      console.log("onload");
      $scope.stages.push('onload');
      $scope.$apply();
    };
    fileReader.onprogress = function(event) {
      console.log("onprogress");
      $scope.stages.push('onprogress');
      $scope.$apply();
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };
});
app.directive('download', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: `<button ng-click="download()">
          Download
               </button>
              <div ng-repeat="stage in stages track by $index">{{stage}}</div>`,
    scope: {},
    controller: 'downloadCtrl',
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <download></download>
</div>
```

Также на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/oas31zzk/).

Почему это происходит?

P.S. Workaround знаю, можно проверить, находимся мы уже в `$digest` цикле или нет, с помощью `$scope.$$phase`.
Интересует именно, почему так происходит.

## Update

Вроде бы событие `onloadstart` в Мозиле уже идет в `$digest` цикле. Остальные два события `onload` и `onprogress` как и ожидается выполняются вне контекста ангуляра.

## Update 2

Добавил печать call stack. Действительно, в Мозиле событие `onloadstart` происходит синхронно.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('downloadCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.stages = [];

  function printStack(note) {
    console.log((new Error("printStack: " + note)).stack.toString());
  }
  $scope.download = function() {
    let file = new Blob(["Sample text data"]);
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    printStack('sync');
    fileReader.onloadstart = function() {
      console.log("onloadstart");
      $scope.stages.push('onloadstart');
      printStack('async');
      //$scope.$apply();
    };
    fileReader.onload = function() {
      console.log("onload");
      $scope.stages.push('onload');
      printStack('async');
      $scope.$apply();
    };
    fileReader.onprogress = function(event) {
      console.log("onprogress", event);
      $scope.stages.push('onprogress');
      printStack('async');
      $scope.$apply();
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };
});
app.directive('download', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: `<button ng-click="download()">
          Download
               </button>
              <div ng-repeat="stage in stages track by $index">{{stage}}</div>`,
    scope: {},
    controller: 'downloadCtrl',
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <download></download>
</div>
```

Comment: Поставьте точку останова и посмотрите стек вызовов. У меня есть подозрение, что `fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);` вызывает событие `onloadstart` синхронно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вы правы, событие `onloadstart` происходит синхронно. Почему так работает, наверное, спрашивать нужно не здесь)) Оформите ответом?

Comment: О каком ответе речь? Пока мы выяснили суть проблемы, причины разного поведения в разных браузерах не раскрыты.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Причина - выполнение события `onloadstart` синхронно. Суть, почему оно так, нам смогут рассказать только разработчики *Firefox*. Думаю, они здесь мне не ответят))